# error while consuming WCF service from VB6 script

Tags: wcf, iis, vb6

I got a simple WCF service written in C#. I need to consume the service from VB script using MS SOAP Toolkit 3.0. I wrote a simple client code like that:

```
   Dim client
   Set client = CreateObject("MSSOAP.SoapClient30")
   client.MSSoapInit "http://localhost:8888/MyService.svc?wsdl"
```

I am hosting my service on IIS 7.5 (Windows 7). The error shows up during .MSSoapInit invocation:

> HRESULT=0x1: result 0x1 incorrect function.
>   - WSDLReader:Could not find '/definitions/service' inside the 'default' namespace of the wsdl file HRESULT=0x80070057: The parameter is incorrect.
>      WSDLReader:Analyzing the WSDL file failed HRESULT=0x80070057: The parameter is incorrect.
>      Client:One of the parameters supplied is invalid. HRESULT=0x80070057: The parameter is incorrect.

If i run project from Visual Studio (ASP.NET development server) i don't have any troubles, i can consume service from my client code. Generated wsdl-schemas are equal for both cases (except the port number)

What could be a reason of this behaviour?

Comment: Try passing username/password like this `http://user:pass@localhost...`

Comment: the same stuff, but thank you...